# Capacitors for Jacobs ladder?

Tags: high-voltage, voltage-doubler

Can I use 104 k 250v ceramic capacitors in a Jacobs ladder circuit? Do I need to use higher rated ones? I'm salvaging some of my components from a used CFL. [image]

Comment: If that cap will be used for input decoupling (i.e. across the line voltage input terminals) then yes, you can.

Comment: I never want less than about \$15\:\textrm{kV}\$ for a Jacob's ladder and usually shoot for much more. But you need to be aware of the fact that you are already getting into soft x-rays by then. For practical circuits have a look at: http://www.diyphysics.com/category/instrumentation/high-voltage-power-supply/